# How to read a txt file from an existing directory

Tags: c++

i am trying to read a txt file from my directory , this i got so far. its compiling but print nothing.

```
char printFile() {
  fstream file("proj1_test1.txt");
  char file01;
  char page[5][6];
  file.open("proj1_test1.txt");

  for(int i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < numOfColumns; j++){
      file >> file01;
      page[i][j] = file01;
      //cout << page[i][j] << endl;
    }
  }
  cout << "file loaded " << endl;
  cout << file << endl; 

  file.close();


  return 0;
}
```

The file which i am trying to read and print contains this

```
 F F R R R
 F F R R R
 F F R R R
 F F R R R
 F F R R R
 F F R R R
```

Comment: Did you check if the file properly opened or not?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This will properly open a file relative to the current working directory (CWD), which may not behave as you expect if it's run from a script or a GUI application. It won't be relative to the path where the code was **compiled**, but rather, where it's run from. This also may not be the current directory the program is in.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fstream file("proj1_test1.txt");
```

opened the file.

```
file.open("proj1_test1.txt");
```

opened the file again without first closing it. Opening a filestream that is already open places the file stream in an error state that must be `clear`ed before you can read from or write to it.

To fix: remove `file.open("proj1_test1.txt");`

A warning: This file is being opened with a relative path. As pointed out in the question's comments, a program does not necessarily run from the same location as the executable. Search term for further information: Working Directory. If after the above correction the file still does not open, make certain that the program is running from the same folder as the file you want opened. The `getcwd` function may help with this.

A suggestion: After any operation on any stream (this includes opening, reading, 
 and writing) test the stream state to make sure the operation succeeded. Example:

```
fstream file("proj1_test1.txt");
if (file)
{
    // do stuff with file
}
else
{
    // failed to open. Warn user
}
```

When reading you want something along the lines of

```
if (file >> page[i][j])
{
    // read successful. can use page[i][j]
}
else
{
    // read failed. Warn user
    // do not use page[i][j]
}
```